# Hyphenation command does not work with Greek words

Tags: hyphenation, babel

I am relatively new to LaTex. I am struggling to write a report that contains mixed Greek and English words. The main language of the report is Greek. Therefore, I use the babel package. However, latex keeps hyphenating the word "είναι" wrongly as "ε-ί-ναι" instead of "εί-ναι". Therefore, I tried to use the `\hyphenation` command as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[a4paper,inner=3.5cm,outer=2.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenx}



\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[tight]{subfigure}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{cite}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{greek}

\hyphenation{εί-ναι}

\end{document}
```

However the `\hyphenation` command as used above generates the error: `Improper \hyphenation will be flushed \hyphenation{ε`.

Is there a solution to this problem? Note that I tried the `\babelhyphenation[greek]{εί-ναι}` command but it is not recognized by LaTeX.

I installed MikTex 2.9 (32-bit) for Win7.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

This is a tough problem with `pdflatex`. You can't use Greek letters in `\hyphenation`, because they are really treated as if they were commands that eventually instruct TeX to typeset the corresponding letter.

Such a problem should be reported to the maintainers of the hyphenation patterns, that can be reached through the mailing list http://tug.org/mailman/listinfo/tex-hyphen

For solving the problem at hand, one has to see what character slots are occupied by the characters when a Greek font is used. This correspondence turns out:

- ε = `0x65`
- ί = `0xD0`
- ν = `0x6E`
- α = `0x61`
- ι = `0x69`

Here's the complete table:

[image]

So we have to use TeX's internal mechanism for representing arbitrary characters, that is `^^xy`, where `x` and `y` are hexadecimal digits (lowercase for letters `abcdef`).

There is another problem, though: the `utf8` or `utf8x` options to `inputenx` make some of these characters active (which is how the Greek letters on your screen are transformed into glyphs to be typeset).

Well, this is the final concoction; the `\detokenize` command avoids the characters being interpreted in a special way. At the end I typeset the word in a zero width `\parbox`, so TeX will show all feasible hyphenation points.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[a4paper,inner=3.5cm,outer=2.5cm]{geometry}

%%% This is better than `utf8x`
\usepackage[LGRx,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
%%% Comment the two lines above and uncomment the line below for using `utf8x`
%\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenx}


\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

%%% Use Greek hyphenation rules   
\begin{hyphenrules}{greek}
\hyphenation{\detokenize{^^65^^d0-^^6e^^61^^69}}
\end{hyphenrules}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[tight]{subfigure}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{cite}

\begin{document}

\parbox{0pt}{\hspace{0pt}είναι}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @NikosA. Sorry for it being so complicated. Things would be much easier with XeLaTeX. Actually, with XeLaTeX the word hyphenates as "εί-ναι" by default.