# Hyphenation issue with pdfLatex and Greek

Tags: pdftex, babel, hyphenation, greek

Ok so, we have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,final]{memoir}

\usepackage[T1,LGR]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

% Fonts
\usepackage[p,osf]{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinegc}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage{newtxtt}

\begin{document}
    \selectlanguage{greek}
    \parbox{0pt}{\hspace{0pt}επίλυση}
\end{document}
```

Which produces the following output:

[image]

However, I am not happy with this hyphenation so I add the following line to the preamble:

```
\babelhyphenation[greek]{επί-λυ-ση}
```

which produces an error, namely:

```
! Improper \hyphenation will be flushed.
\LGR\textsigma ->s\noboundary
```

It seems to have a problem with words hyphenated before a `σ`. Any suggestions?

**Edit:** I've tried following this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118000/hyphenation-command-does-not-work-with-greek-words?noredirect=1&lq=1) and the encoding map from [here](http://www.eutypon.gr/eutypon/pdf/e2008-20/e20-a03.pdf), but to no avail. So I've tried using the primitive `\hyphenate` as follows:

```
\hyphenation{\detokenize{^^65^^70^^d0-^^6c^^75-^^73^^68}}
```

but both

```
\parbox{0pt}{\hspace{0pt}επίλυση}\par
\parbox{0pt}{\hspace{0pt}\detokenize{^^65^^70^^d0^^6c^^75^^73^^68}}\par
```

produce the same output as before. I've also tried adding the tonos accent seperately on `ι` as:

```
\parbox{0pt}{\hspace{0pt}\detokenize{^^65^^70^^27^^69^^6c^^75^^73^^68}}\par
```

but when trying to define a hyphenation pattern as

```
\hyphenation{\detokenize{^^65^^70^^27^^69-^^6c^^75-^^73^^68}}
```

I get the following error:

```
! Not a letter.
<inserted text> ep'
                   i-lu-sh
l.19 ...kenize{^^65^^70^^27^^69-^^6c^^75-^^73^^68}
                                                  }
```

However, note that even without that hyphenation pattern it produces a different result, i.e.:

[image]

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/118007/2388

Comment: I have seen this topic, but this refers to the ```\hyphenation``` command. Wouldn't using the babel equivalent be free of such problems? Because it works fine with other words.

Comment: Also, the referenced table does not contain ```σ```, only ```ς``` (twice).

Comment: at the end babel has to use the primitive \hyphenation too.  And if it works depends on the char, e.g. ε and π are ok as they map to simple chars, ί not as it uses an accent and σ gives an error as its definition contains the \noboundary command.

Comment: You’ve probably thought of this already, but if you aren’t forced to use PDFLaTeX, you can use `fontspec` and `polyglossia`. That’s what somebody reaching this question from a search engine probably ought to do.